# trying to convert python firebase info to json

Tags: python, json, firebase

I have a Python code where I can fech the data from firebase cloud firestore just with this code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("firebaseCredentials.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

#read data
#Getting a Document with a known ID

results = db.collection('users').document('HtregtuuDDVWglz9DjobFGH9jMo1').collection('chats').get()
for result in results:
    print(result.to_dict())
```

With this code the result is something like that:

```
{'message': 'works'}
{'message': 'this is a test'}
```

Also I have a json file with some random string as you can see here:

```
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hey :-)",
      ]
    }
}
```

Okey, here is my dude, is there any way to get the data that I get from firebase (example: 'this is a test') , convert that info to json and put it in a jsonfile (or in the same file ) like that:

```
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "firebase data1",
      "patterns": [
        HERE THE FIREBASE DATA (ex: this is a test)
      ],
      "responses": [
        HERE THE FIREBASE DATA (ex: this is a test)
      ]
    },

    {
      "tag": "firebase data22",
      "patterns": [
        HERE THE FIREBASE DATA2 (ex: works)
      ],
      "responses": [
        HERE THE FIREBASE DATA2 (ex: works)
      ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: does `firebase data1` specifically pair with `this is a test`? IE. is the order of the firebase response important when tag is set?

Comment: No it doenst, is not important, I mean, once I get the data from firebase, just I want to put the data (without any important the order) in the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reformat your firebase data in the "intents" structure, it looks like you can:

```
intents = {"intents": []}
results = db.collection('users').document('HtregtuuDDVWglz9DjobFGH9jMo1').collection('chats').get()
for index, result in enumerate(results):
    data = result.to_dict()
    intents["intents"].append({
        "tag": f"firebase data{index}",
        "patterns": [data["message"]],
        "responses": [data["message"]]
    })

print(intents)
```